# $.post("@Url.Action not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an option that adds each project to archive and now I am trying to show all the archive project.

```
   $.post("@Url.Action("ShowArchive", "Project")");
```

ShowArchive in project controller :

```
public JsonResult ShowArchive(int id)
{
    List<Project> projectList = (List<Project>)projectService.ShowArchivebyid(id);
    return Json(projectList.ConvertAll<object>(Project.ToJsonObject), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public IEnumerable<Project> ShowArchivebyid(int id)
{
    Project project = GetProject(id);
    Expression<Func<Project, bool>> constraint = null;
    constraint = e => (e.Archive == 1);
    IEnumerable<Project> result_list = projectRepository.GetMany(constraint);

    return result_list.ToList<Project>();
}
```

in javascript console:

```
POST http://localhost:4991/Project/ShowArchive 500 (Internal Server Error) library.min.js:4
send library.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax library.min.js:4
f.(anonymous function) library.min.js:4
(anonymous function) localhost/:417
f.event.dispatch library.min.js:3
h.handle.i
```

Comment: Pass the `id` parameter to the action or make it nullable: `int? id`.

Comment: For starters, you aren't passing an id to ShowArchive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the javascript call to something like ...

```
 $.post("@Url.Action("ShowArchive", "Project", new { id = your_id } )");
```

(untested)